# How to recognize CR and LF at each response from MC60 at the start and end of strings?

Tags: c, embedded

For more than an year I have not touched C and now I have to make this project.
I am writing code for sending MC60 AT commands via AVR microcontroller, however I have just made a basic function of Uart for sending the test commands and read commands to the MC60 and rightnow just testing on Virtual terminal in Proteus as how the commands are being recieved. At the end of every command I am sending CR and LF using their Hex codes directly through UART, till here it is fine, but when I have to recieve responses from MC60 they are also having CR and LF at their beginning and end, and my code is not able to extract the actual response data out of it excluding the commands. I just want my actual response data to be stored in a string that I can return from a function. Below is the example of my code for fetching response:

```
unsigned char uart_RX()
{
while(!UCSRA & (1<<RXC));
return UDR;
}    

void response(char *rec) //function to fetch the response in string format
{
char x;
do
{
    x = uart_RX();
    *rec = x;
    rec++;
}
while(x!=NULL);
return;
//_delay_ms(10);
 } 

void main()
{
char buf[200];
char resp[200];
char cr, lf;
uart_init(12);
_delay_ms(1000);
send_readcmd(READNAVINFO); //function that sends "<CR><LF>AT+QGNSSRD?<CR><LF>" command through my own defined library of AT commands
while(1)
{   
    cr = uart_RX();
    if (cr==0x0D)
    {
        lf = uart_RX();
        if (lf==0x0A)
        {
            response(buf);
            snprintf(resp, sizeof(buf), buf); //I feel resp will store the buf data without CR and LF

        }
    }
 }
}
```

I expect the actual response data from MC60, after sending the read command using send_readcmd() to be stored in resp char array. Currently it is recognizing the commands I sense but the response is a mess, I am unable to parse that response properly.
Please somebody help me and guide me how to fetch the response and separate the actual response data from CR and LF both sides and store actual data in an array resp.

Comment: Your code is first reading the `cr` and `lf`, and only then it is reading `buff`. I bet it is not the sequence you want. Just read everything within the `response` and make these to terminate your reading loop. BTW, I doubt your response is `\0`-terminated, so checking against it is probably wrong.

Comment: @EugeneSh.  Yes you are right my respone is not \0 terminated, what I meant to code was till the value at Uart reciever is not becoming NULL. Now I see I was wrong here even, please could you suggest me a better way to write this code and solve the problem

Comment: Recommend instead upon receiving a `'\r'` or `'\n'` **and** with no prior input to quietly throw that data away and look for more.

Comment: `... while(x!='\0');` (which is the same as `while(x!=NULL);`) is strange.  Do you expect a `'\0'` to be transmitted?

Comment: There are nominally  both zero so it makes no difference.

Comment: @chux no i just want it to read the response till the response is available at UART reciever port then I just want to separate the begining and ending with CR and LF and store actual response in resp

Comment: how does `uart_RX()` work?  Does it block until a character is read? If not what does it do when no characters are available - does it return 0, or the last character, or something else?

Comment: @AShelly uart_RX simply recieves the data, i have added that function too in the above code

Comment: Serial communications is a real-time activity - there is no thing as "simply", without considering time.  It is absolutely possible to check for incoming characters too quickly, or too slowly.However, the implementation you just posted does block until a character is ready, and is unlikely to be too slow. The remaining risk is receiving no data - you probably need a timeout.

Comment: @AShelly so if I set a timer to run for two seconds and refresh the value of buf after every two seconds to see if i recieve a CR and LF then follow up with what Chux has suggested would that do?

Comment: No, thats almost certain to lose data, unless the hardware has a deep serial fifo. To implement a timeout, you would need to exit the while loop inside `uart_RX` after a certain number of cycles, and signal an error condition.  Without that, it is possible your program will hang forever, as you end up waiting for a character that will never be sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recommend instead upon receiving a `'\r'` or `'\n'` **and** with no prior input to quietly throw that data away and look for more.

When a `'\r'` **or** `'\n'` is received with prior input, identify that as a end-of-command.

```
// I'd also expect some timeout criteria, yet that is TBD code
void response(char *rec, size_t size) {
  char ch;
  while ((ch = uart_RX()) == '\r' || ch == '\n') {
    ;
  }
  do {
    if (size > 1) {
      size--; 
      *rec++ = ch;
    }
    ch = uart_RX();
  } while (ch != '\r' && ch != '\n');
  if (size > 0) {
    *rec = '\0';
  }
}
```

Usage

```
while (1) {   
  response(buf, sizeof buf);
  printf("%s", buf);
}
```

Comment: I see thanks, this might work and I got where I was going wrong, Thanx alot @chux